# Error when calling the method timeseries_dataset_from_array from Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm going through the tutorial given in:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series

Funny thing, when I ran the code I got the error:

`AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.keras.preprocessing' has no attribute 'timeseries_dataset_from_array'`

I tried explicitly importing the method like:

`from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import timeseries_dataset_from_array`

but then:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'timeseries_dataset_from_array'`

I'm using Spyder 4, Python 3.6.9, TensorFlow 2.1.0 and Keras 2.2.4-tf. Can anyone clarify this to me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's introduced in tensorflow 2.3.0, so you need to update your tensorflow.
[tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/timeseries_dataset_from_array)

Answer (score 0):

The function is now moved to utils from v2.15

Use [tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/timeseries_dataset_from_array) instead